# Where does log4net debugformat message go under .net?

Tags: .net, log4net

I make calls to the log4net debugformat(). But I don't see it under the eventviewer. However, info/warning and error all  show up fine.

I checked the event viewer settings and see that I can enable/disable the info/error/warning messages. But don't see a checkbox for debug. How can I get the debug messages to show up?

Comment: Please add some details, including your log4net config file, to help us understand what is not working for you.  My guess is your level needs to be set: <level value="DEBUG" />

Answer (score 1):

Log4Net can log a number of different appenders based on your configuration. These may be a db table, a text file, email address or indeed the event log. As such there is no fixed answer to your question - it all depends how it is configured.

Take a look at the [configuration documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) for examples of how to configure each one.